# Referencing Other Documents by String rather than ObjectId

Tags: mongodb

Let's say I have two collections:

`Products` and `Categories`.

The latter collection's documents have 2 fields:

- _id (`BSON ObjectId`)
- Name (String)

The latter collection's documents have 3 fields:

- _id (`BSON ObjectId`)
- Name (String)
- Products (Array of Strings)

Assume I have the following `Product` document:

`{ "_id" : ObjectId("AAA"), "name" : "Shovel" }`

Let's say I have the following `Category` document:

`{ "_id" : ObjectId("BBB"), "Name" : "Gardening", "Products" : ["AAA"] }`

For purposes of this example, assume that `AAA` and `BBB` are legitimate ObjectId's - example: `ObjectId("523c7df5c30cc960b235ddee")` where they would equal the inner ObjectId's string.

Should the `Products` field be stored as `ObjectId(...)`'s rather than as Strings?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it really matters that much.

I'm pretty sure that the ObjectId format encodes a hex number, so it is probably slightly more efficient with memory and bandwidth.  I have done it both ways.  As long as you decide, for each field, how you are going to encode it, either will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you consistently use the same type (so that comparisons happen correctly), the difference is:

1. An `ObjectId` cannot be compared to a `String` representation of the same `ObjectId` value. Thus, `ObjectId("523c7df5c30cc960b235ddee")` is not equal to `"523c7df5c30cc960b235ddee"`.
2. `ObjectId`s, when stored natively, will be stored as 12 bytes, plus field name
3. An `ObjectId`, when stored as a string, will be commonly stored in 24 bytes (as it will be converted to a hexadecimal number), plus field name
4. Comparisons can be made more SLIGHTLY more efficiently with the 12 byte number, as it's comparing fewer bytes. It won't matter in most types of usage though, so it's a micro-optimization (but something you should know)
5. Bonus -- if you don't use short abbreviated field names, the size benefit of using an `ObjectId` natively as 12 bytes really won't matter, as the field names will far outweigh the size of bytes when stored as a string.

I'd recommend storing them as native `ObjectId`s. Some drivers can optionally and transparently translate to an `ObjectId` to a `String` and back so that the client code can more easily manipulate it. The C# driver for example can do this, and I've used it so that when serializing to JSON, the `ObjectId` is in a simple format that is easily consumed in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

This will matter most when you try to find the details of a product starting from the Categories collection.

Since there are no server side JOIN in Mongo, your code will have to match documents together. [ObjectIDs are encoded as 12 bytes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/), which you can easilly compare in any language. Using either strings or object ids does not really matter.

The real issue you are facing is one of data normalization (or lack thereof). If you store the `Name` field in your `Categories` documents, instead of the ObjectID, you will be able to return the products names in a single call (instead of multiple calls, 1 for each products of the category).

It feels wrong the first time you do it. After all, you will have to update many documents if you ever change the name of a product, which might or might not be frequent. You have to model your data by thinking of the way your application will use it.

Finally, index the `Name` attribute in the `Prodcuts` collection. Getting the details of a product, starting with the string you found in a `Categories` document will be fast.

Another way to do it is to not to have a Categories collection at all, but to add a `Category` attribute to your `Products` document. You can find documents that have the `{'Category':'Gardening'}`. Indexing the `Category` field will probably be a good idea.

Again, ObjectID or String does not matter much. It is about modeling your data thinking of how your application will use it.

Comment: In response to: `If you store the Name field ... in a single call" - I could achieve the same if I properly use an `ObjectId(...)` rather than String, right?

Comment: Not if you want to display the Names of the products in a category. I imagine your application will show categories, with a list of product names to choose from. You would already have the names. I will update the answer with another way to look at it.