# is ObjectId faster than String in fetching?

Tags: performance, mongodb

I'm trying to make the correct annotations for best performances
I have this collection : posts that has field author which is annoted string but contains the _id of another collection which is users :

```
users{
 _id:objectId(BLABLA)
}
posts{
 author : "BLABLA"
}
```

I want to know if I'm fetching posts by user as strings  , is  faster than fetching as objectId ? 

thanks for answers..

Comment: It would really surprise me when there would be a notable difference.

Comment: I wandered a little bit and found this :http://stackoverflow.com/a/18959506/3062150
What catched my attention beside size storage is the comparison , as string it would compare the whole string as for objectId it compares fewer bytes

Comment: To compare two strings you only need to compare until you found the first byte which is different. The same applies to binary arrays like ObjectId's.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Referencing Other Documents by String rather than ObjectId](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18950948/referencing-other-documents-by-string-rather-than-objectid)

Comment: Ok I understand. it is indeed duplicate