# What is it needed for id subdocuments

Tags: mongoose

Subdocuments are documents embedded in other documents. In Mongoose, this means you can nest schemas in other schemas.

When I use subdocuments, Mongoose automatically creates an id. How is this used? I do not understand why this is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The subdocument `_id` is used in the same way as document `_id` is: To fetch data more efficient.

You can use the `_id` to find documents like [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EPcQL1TKhgs)

```js
db.collection.find({
  "subdocument._id": 1
})
```

But, why use `ObjectId` instead another type?

Well, efficiency... that's all.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18959506/13464279) answer where explain that `ObjectId` is saved as 12 bytes while String are 24 bytes. So is faster compare 12 bytes to fetch documents instead of 24.