# How to define object in array with Mongoose/MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to get these data structure:

```
{
"_id": 5ff7822037fbe047d8fa6496,
"user_id": 5ff7822037fbe047d8fa1234,
"todos"[
          {
            "task": "Do something",
            "complited: false
          }
       ]
}
```

can't create array with object

Here is my code but it does not work proparly

```
//file TodoList.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const todo = require('../models/Todo')
const TodoList = mongoose.Schema({
    user_id: String,
    todos: [Object]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("TodoList", TodoList)
```

```
//Todo.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const Todo = mongoose.Schema(
    {task: String,
    complited: Boolean}
)

module.exports = mongoose.model("Todo", Todo)
```

```
//file todos.js

const express = require('express')
const Todo = require('../models/Todo')
const TodoList = require('../models/TodoList')
const router = express.Router()


router.post('/create', async (req,res)=>{
    
    const newTodo = new Todo({
        task: req.body.task,
        complited: req.body.complited
    })
    const newTodoList = new TodoList({
        user_id: req.body.user_id,
        todos: [newTodo]
    })
    
    try {
        const savedTodoList =await newTodoList.save()
        res.json(savedTodoList)
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).json(err)
    }
})
module.exports = router
```

When i send req such

```
{
    "user_id": "5ff7822037fbe047d8fa6496",
    "todos":[{"task": "Do something", "complited": false}]
}
```

I got this

```
{
    "todos": [
        {
            "_id": "5ffa1862a0431052b4111f80",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ],
    "_id": "5ffa1862a0431052b4111f81",
    "user_id": "5ff7822037fbe047d8fa6496",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Can you help me create one worker schema instead of two or just fix these
Thank you
I searched web and stackoverflow but did find something good for me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this schema:

```js
const YourSchemaName = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    user_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    todos:[{
      task: String,
      complited: Boolean
    }]
   }
)
```

You can see that `todos` is defined as an object list. Objects that compound the list has two properties: `task` and `complited`.

In this way you have data structure you want.

Also, checking if it works you can use `validate()` method from Mongoose:

```js
var validate = new YourModel({
    "_id": "5ff7822037fbe047d8fa6496",
    "user_id": "5ff7822037fbe047d8fa1234",
    "todos":[
              {
                "task": "Do something",
                "complited": false
              }
           ]
    }).validateSync()
console.log("valid = ",validate)
```

If `valid` value is undefined then validation worked ok, otherwise, `validate` contains the error given.

And also, of course, using `save()` method will works too:

```js
await new YourModel({
    "_id": "5ff7822037fbe047d8fa6496",
    "user_id": "5ff7822037fbe047d8fa1234",
    "todos":[
              {
                "task": "Do something",
                "complited": false
              }
           ]
    }).save()
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. One more question. You wrote user_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId. if i write user_id: String what is difference?

Comment: They are different values. The mainly difference is efficiency to fetch documents by that value. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18959506/13464279) answer. ObjectId is stored as 12 bytes but an String are 24 bytes. So is faster compare 12 bytes than 24. The schema will works ok and queries too. Also mongoose parse String (if it has a good format) to ObjectId, so there is no problem using String. But is better set a field as ObjectId rather than String by the efficiency.